# Cannot delete a file using ASP DeleteFile method

Tags: file-io, asp-classic, filesystemobject

I'm trying to delete an image file whenever a user clicks a link to delete it.  I get no errors, and the error number is zero.  However, the file is not deleted.  I can save the photos file, but not delete them for some reason.  Here is my code:

```
PhotoFile = "\images\networkPartners\" & rs(fieldName)
PhotoPath = Server.MapPath(PhotoFile)
dim ServerFSO
Set ServerFSO=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if ServerFSO.FileExists(PhotoPath) then
    response.Write(PhotoPath)

    ServerFSO.DeleteFile(PhotoPath)
end if
set ServerFSO=nothing
```

When the response.write hits, I do get the actual file path.  ("C:/web/images", etc.)  All the way up to the file name.  All capitalization is correct and so forth.  Again, no errors at all when I do the "on error resume next" and write out the error number and string.

Calling:

```
    ServerFSO.DeleteFile(PhotoPath, true)
```

results in the error:

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a0414'

Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub

/folder/file_edit.asp, line 32

ServerFSO.DeleteFile(PhotoPath, true)
-------------------------------------^
```

Comment: This looks like classic ASP, not ASP.NET - are you sure you tagged correctly?

Comment: Sorry, it is.  I tried putting in the tag "asp", but it said it didn't exist.  Didn't think to put "classic" in front of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if your files are marked with readonly attribute. If so then use

```
FileSystemObject.DeleteFile filename, true
```

this will force delete a readonly file.

Comment: I actually tried that, but got the error "Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub"

ServerFSO.DeleteFile(PhotoPath, true)
-------------------------------------^

Comment: Did you try calling this Sub without parentheses? OR try CALL FileSystemObject.DeleteFile(filename, true)

Comment: Well I don't know how I would call that without parentheses, but I tried to call FileSystemObject.etc with the same resulting error.

Comment: Did you try ServerFSO.DeleteFile PhotoPath, True

Comment: Yes, that one worked.  Thank you.  It's odd that all the examples show that with parentheses around it.

Answer (score 1):

My testing of this example code shows that parentheses do work in this example.

```
<%
Set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fo=fs.GetFolder("c:\")
Set tfile=fo.CreateTextFile("test.txt",true)
tfile.WriteLine("Hello World!")
tfile.Close
if fs.FileExists("c:\test.txt") then
  fs.DeleteFile("c:\test.txt")
end if
set tfile=nothing
set fo=nothing
set fs=nothing
%>
```

However, it will fail when a force parameter is added:

```
<%
Set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fo=fs.GetFolder("c:\")
Set tfile=fo.CreateTextFile("test.txt",true)
tfile.WriteLine("Hello World!")
tfile.Close
if fs.FileExists("c:\test.txt") then
  fs.DeleteFile("c:\test.txt",True)
end if
set tfile=nothing
set fo=nothing
set fs=nothing
%>
```

Answer (score -1):

It should work without brackets

```
DeleteFile "c:\test.txt",True
```

but there are some folder who are protected and you have to run as administrator. I don't know how to do it with an script, because it hasn't the choice "run as" in the context menu.

Comment: This question was answered back in December of last year...  Thanks anyway though.